# Extra left space on Tikz matrix node

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, tikz-matrix, tikz-node

I use the following homemade color legend for Tikz drawings (the code this given at the end):

[image]

But when I tried to print two color rectangles horizontally, an extra space appears on the left (see green arrow on the figure below, added for explanation purpose only), the code is given at the end:

[image]

**Is there a way to obtain the desired output (second figure) without extra space on the left ?**

### Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    
        \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        
        \path ([xshift=0.07cm,yshift=0cm]current bounding box.north west)%
        node[matrix,anchor=north west,cells={nodes={font=\sffamily,anchor=west}},
        draw,thick,inner sep=1ex]{%
            \path (0,0); \node {\bfseries Legend :}; & \\
            \filldraw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5)  ; & \node[above, pos=0.1]{main script};\\
            \filldraw[red] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5)  ; & \node[above, pos=0.1]{functions};\\
        };%
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[]

\path ([xshift=0.07cm,yshift=0cm]current bounding box.north west)%
node[matrix,anchor=north west,cells={nodes={font=\sffamily,anchor=west}},
draw,thick,inner sep=1ex]{%
    \path (0,0); \node {\bfseries Legend :}; & \\
    \filldraw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5)  ; & \node[above, pos=0.1]{main script};\\
    \filldraw[red] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5)  ; & \node[above, pos=0.1,]{functions};\\
    \filldraw[gray] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5); \node[above]{\hspace{3.5em} /}; \filldraw[yellow] (0.85,0) rectangle (1.35,0.5); & \node[above, pos=0.1]{other};\\
};%
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\hspace` is causing the shift. Instead place the `/` as a node:

`\filldraw[gray] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5); \node at (.42,.25){/}; \filldraw[yellow] (0.85,0) rectangle (1.35,0.5); & \node[above, pos=0.1]{other};\\`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without `TiKZ`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
        
\fbox{\sffamily\begin{tabular}{lc}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Legend:}\\[2mm]
\textcolor{blue}{\rule{5mm}{5mm}} & \raisebox{1.5mm}{main script}\\
\textcolor{red}{\rule{5mm}{5mm}} & \raisebox{1.5mm}{functions}\\
\textcolor{gray}{\rule{5mm}{5mm}}\raisebox{1.5mm}{/}\textcolor{yellow}{\rule{5mm}{5mm}} & \raisebox{1.5mm}{other}\\
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]